# VideoView SeekTo working abnormally on different devices - Android

Tags: java, android, video, android-videoview

I am using this code on video view to seek to custom position but it is working fine on samsung devices but on sony devices the video seeks to the start position(beginning)

**I want to get video to the position where it was last time paused**

Creating Video View:

```
        VideoView mVideoPlayer.setVideoPath(ViDpath);

        MediaController mCd = new MediaController(this);
        mVideoPlayer.setMediaController(mCd);
        mVideoPlayer.requestFocus();
```

Pause and Play works fine:

```
        mVideoPlayer.pause();
        mVideoPlayer.start();
```

This works abnormally:

```
        mVideoPlayer.seekTo(anyCustomPosition);
```

**Testing:**
I tested it further on different devices.

- Moto X 2014 Lollipop: *It works abnormally, sometimes video continues
  and sometimes it starts over.*
- Samsung S4 KitKat: *Works better but dont seeks to the exact position.*
- Sony Xperia Z KitKat: *Video always starts over(from the beginning).*

Is there any alternate?
Or a way to fix it?

Comment: Hey Salmaan, I currently have the same issue. Did you find any solution to this? Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisPont found the solution after your comment. The video codec h264 have seeking issues, change it to mpeg4