# VideoView SeekTo working smoothly or delay on different devices - Android

Tags: android, video, seektotime

I'm developing a function that I click next button then the **pause video** will seekto next part and **start**.For example when video.getCurrentPosition is 8000, I click button to make video seekto(10000),because **the video show same content between 8000 and 10000.**

This function on some android devices runs smoothly,such as `Samsung s6 edge,OnePlus,Xiaomi,Smartison`...

But the issue is that on some devices,such as Huawei,Moto Nexus 6,
when video on 8000 and I click the button,it has some "`delay time`".It looks like about 1sec. later,the video finally starts.

By contrast,I specially change the **seekto(10200),which is wrong parameter**,and these "problem devices" runs smoothly likes "normal devices".However,the video on previous "`normal devices`" skip some frame and start at 10200.

Is anyone know why cause this issue?Hope your answer,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Was the video encoded using `h264`?  Re-encoding as using the `mpeg4` codec, as suggested [in a comment to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251368/videoview-seekto-working-abnormally-on-different-devices-android), has resolved for me a problem of very odd `seekTo` behaviour by an Android `ViewView`.

To check the encoding, and to re-encode, you might be able to use `ffmpeg`.

`$ ffprobe <inputfile>
...
...
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 ...
...`

That showed the the file is encoded using `h264`, which is more recent and generally produces better quality for the same bitrate as `mpeg4`, but is (presumably as a consequence) harder to seek through, at least for the Android `VideoView`.

To encode as `mpeg4` the following worked for me, but [the `ffmpeg` wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MPEG-4) has more detail.

`$ ffmpeg -i <inputfile> -c:v libxvid <outputfile>`